Adding values from a data array into a mesh
I am trying to make a .nc file for an elevation dataset that I have stored in an 2-D array of size
(39600, 42600)
In order to get the latitude and longitude values, I created a mesh like system using np.linespace as follows:
nx = 42600
ny = 39600
resolution = 0.000833
lonmin = 64.500000000
lonmax = 100.000000000
latmin = 5.000000000
latmax = 38.000000000
lon_values = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, nx)
lat_values = np.linspace(latmin, latmax, ny)
lon_mesh, lat_mesh = np.meshgrid(lon_values, lat_values)
coordinates = np.stack((lat_mesh, lon_mesh), axis=-1)
print("Shape of coordinate grid:", coordinates.shape)

Now into this mesh I wish to add values from the 2-D array as mentioned earlier. The 2-d data array has exact number of data values required to fill up this mesh system but I am not sure how to write this array in sequence into the lat long mest.
How do I proceed further with this problem.
Thank You
I am not sure if the approach I am using is correct for making a lat long system. Any ideas for a better way to do this would also be of great help.

Is there an error occurring? Is the output of a method or property eg shape not what you expect? If the former, what's the error? If the latter, what is your expectation and what is the actual output?
